# Sql statement with BETWEEN - what's wrong with it?

Tags: android, sqlite

empty (not null!)I want to create sql statement as this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1
```

I have a sql in database as this^

```
            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                    URI, 
                    new String[] { col_id, col_2,DATE }, 
                    DATE + " BETWEEN ? AND ?" , 
                    new String[] {dateAsString, stopDate)} ,
                    DATE + " ASC LIMIT 1");

        cursor = database.query(
                table, projection, 
                selection, selectionArgs, 
                null, null, sortOrder);
```

Sql is passed by cursor is null. I copy database to sd card and see it via `SQLiteManager` plugin to FF -0 all data exists and the statement above works in console, so something wring with my sql statement.

Could you tell me wat's wrong wtih that?

**UPDATE** extend question

I store some data which has column Date that saved as:

1. 2012-11-30 09:12:29.392 which pattern yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:s.S
2. Convert this to long and save it to TEXT type of columns in my table
3. So I got something like that 1354197364633

I want to get row which date in databse beetween two values:

```
database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Track WHERE Date BETWEEN ? AND ?", selectionArgs);
```

But I don't succeeded in it. Now I know that is doesn't work at any database but doesn't got a solution. Could you suggest the way how I can resolve my issue?

I try to use the solution below. So in cursor I get this query:

```
SQLiteQuery: SELECT * FROM Track WHERE Date BETWEEN CAST(? AS INT) AND CAST(? AS INT)
```

with this parameters in mBindArgs:

```
{1=1354248261841, 2=1354262663195}
```

I check the date value in track, it lays beyween them, but cursor still returned empty.

Comment: `cursor is null` - your `URI` could be wrong or the `ContentProvider` is buggy and returns `null` (instead of `cursor`).

Comment: Sorry, I misslead you. Cusrsor isn't null, it is empty

Comment: What is DATE? That should be an column name

Comment: Yes, it is a column name. Fixed

Comment: and how you store date ? its string or number ?

Comment: Hello, Selvin. The date in db is a String from Long value which is got as System.currentTime();

Comment: couls you check what you have in `dateAsString` and `stopDate` ... your query looks good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is issue in logic of my app: in some frame between requests to database this rows have been updated so I haven't got my date.

Answer (score 1):

Android's `rawQuery` gets a `String` array for the parameters, and passes them as strings to the database, so the values in your `Date` column are compared to two strings.

If you had used `yyyy-mm-dd...` strings in your database, it would have worked.

You can force the parameters back to integers with a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Track WHERE Date BETWEEN CAST(? AS INT) AND CAST(? AS INT)
```

Comment: Doesn't work :'(. I have got an empty cursor. I also try it in SQLiteManager and it works but not in the app. Could you give me a suggestion?

Comment: Do you get any records with any `WHERE`?

Comment: Yes, I Have a row when pass this statemnt: SELECT * FROM Track WHERE Date >= ? , and "0" instead of wildcard

Comment: So the values in the `Date` column *are* strings, not numbers?

Comment: They are passed as selectioArgs new String[] { arg..argN}, so yes, they are strings. Can I passed numbers in parameterd statement?

Comment: It is unbelievable, but when I hardcoded my values as cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TRACK  WHERE Date >= CAST(1354267555324 AS INT) AND Date <= CAST(1354281986775 AS INT)", null); I ahve gor my data! So something wrong with the type of data which I passed as selectiosArgs. Does anyone know how to pass integer values to String sql statement?

Comment: Please show the exact code that creates `selectionArgs` (or `mBindArgs`, or whatever it's called).

Comment: I have got an error in my app: in some frame between requests to database this rows have been updated so I haven't got my row. Thanks for you help.